# How to check image position and snap into place in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Im trying to build a basic Jigsaw app for iPad however i am very new to objective c and xcode, meaning this is my first go at a fully working app.

Iv been following some tutorials online and have built a very basic three image jigsaw and have successfully managed to get this to operate. However I would like to be able to snap the images into place when the user drags over the correct area and also display an animation or sound.

Im a little lost with this I understand I will need to specify the x and y coordinates for each piece of the puzzle however how do i then check this against if this is the correct location and then fire an action such as animation and sound?

This is my code so far

```
 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch
                             locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view] == image1){
        image1.center = touchLocation;
        NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

                         }
    else if ([touch view] == image2){
        image2.center = touchLocation;
        NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
    }
    else if ([touch view] == image3){
        image3.center = touchLocation;
        NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
    }



}
```

As you can see im loging the x and y however im unsure how to proceed with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say {x1,y1} is the position for the image1,  if you check in `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnded` for the touch to be exactly on {x1,y1} no one's gonna make it.
So let add a marge of error lets name it Epsilon, instead of checking agains a point now we will try to check inside a square (center {x1,y1} and side length of Epsilon): here is some code to help you:

```
float epislon = 20.0;

 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch
                             locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view] == image1)
    {
        image1.center = touchLocation;
        NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

        CGRect rect1= CGRectMake(x1-epsilon/2.0, y1-epsilon/2.0, epsilon, epsilon);
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect1,touchLocation))
        {
            NSLog(@"did find position for image1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks with a little bit of editing and playing around have made this work perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question I too have been thinking about such a simple puzzle apps for kids for a while.

You are on the right track. I believe the trick is to know where the position of original X,Y image should be. Once a the user drags its right on those coordinates then you lock it and throw a happy sound. This is how I would do it. (this is pseudo code)

It would be cool if there is a way to find if you are close enough to x,y coordinates of original image

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch
                             locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touch view] == image1 && image1Locked == NO)
    {
        image1.center = touchLocation;
        NSLog(@"Touch x : %f y : %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

if ( (touchLocation.x == to where x location of image1 should be) &&
     (touchLocation.y == to where y location of image1 should be)
     {
            //lock image by not checking drag anymore
            image1Locked = YES;

            //move the image1 in place where its should be

            //happy sounds
             [self happySounds];

     }

    }
    ...
```

Comment: this was great but as mab said i cant get the user to drop in the exact spot many thanks tho :)